# How to manipulate single register to create endianness swap effect in pic assembly?

Tags: assembly, pic, endianness, cpu-registers

I have to produce following result using pic assembly code:

```
;msb::lsb
7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 ;These bits in single register
;Result should be following:
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Where each number represents bit. This is pretty much changing the endianess of a register. How can this kind of register manipulation be implemented in 8 bit pic assembly? I'm trying to optimize my c code, by using inline assembly and I have the input value put into a register. I have read about the `swapf` instruction, but it would lead into wrong bits as follows: `3,2,1,0,7,6,5,4`
Pic I'm using is `PIC16F887`

Comment: endianness usually refers to byte swapping not bit swapping.  you can do it in a pic or anywhere else in a very manual manner, if you can do table lookups which you probably can you can build two 16 entry tables and do half the byte per lookup and save some time.  You probably dont have 256 bytes to spare for a full table which would be the ideal.

Comment: Please specify the particular PIC family you're targeting. They are quite different, and an approach that makes sense on PIC12 may not necessarily be the best on PIC18.

Comment: [See here](http://www.piclist.com/techref/microchip/math/bit/revbits.htm) for a number of techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this rather depends on your specific 8-bit PIC architecture (PIC16, traditional/enhanced PIC18, etc) and the amount of ROM/RAM you are willing to spend on it.

Below is my untested attempt at implementing the nybble swapping approach dwelch suggested for the PIC16 using ROM tables. It ought to complete in 13 instruction cycles:

```
        ;Reverse nybbles of W separately and merge the results
        MOVWF   tmp1
        CALL    nybble
        MOVWF   tmp2
        SWAPF   tmp1,W
        CALL    nybble
        SWAPF   WREG
        ORF     tmp2,W

        ;Helper function reversing an LSD nybble of W via a table.
        ;The table must _not_ cross a 256-word page!
nybble: ANDLW   0x0F
        ADDWF   PCL
        RETLW   b'0000 : RETLW  b'1000
        RETLW   b'0100 : RETLW  b'1100
        RETLW   b'0010 : RETLW  b'1010
        RETLW   b'0110 : RETLW  b'1110
        RETLW   b'0001 : RETLW  b'1001
        RETLW   b'0101 : RETLW  b'1101
        RETLW   b'0011 : RETLW  b'1011
        RETLW   b'0111 : RETLW  b'1111
```

If you are optimizing for size rather than speed you might try the direct approach of shifting through a pair of accumulators in either direction:

```
        SETC                ;Wind-in the loop condition sentinel
        RLF     input
loop:   RRF     output      ;Go for it!
        RLF     input
        BNZ     loop
```

The loop works by slowly filling `input` with zeroes. Once the sentinel is rotated out into carry, and `input` is zero, the loop terminates.

Comment: Unroll the loop, this is the fastest and most simple solution.

Comment: @GJ: Certainly the simplest but hardly the fastest. The nybble-wise lookup still beats an unrolled loop by 13 to 16 instruction cycles on the PIC16. A full 256-byte ROM table clocks in at 6.

Comment: No, CALL and RETLW tekes 2 cycles so all together 17 cycles!

Comment: @GJ.: You are, of course, correct. I don't know where I pulled that count from. It's worse than that actually, as I believe `ADDWF PCL` has a cycle penalty. I suppose you'll need a full table, or possibly a RAM based one, to beat an unrolled loop.